# Why python configParser.read can only use filename as parameter to read config file

Tags: python-2.7, configparser

My python package directory structure shown as below:

```
./my_package
|---./lib
|   |----__init__.py
|   |----tools.py
|
|----__init__.py
|----my_package.py
|----setting.conf
```

In the tools.py :

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('setting.conf')
debug = config.getboolean('default', 'debug')
```

I don't know why config.read is work. I can get debug value in section default.

Comment: from which directory do you run your script?

Comment: I run my_package.py in the my_package directory. And my_package.py will import tools.

Comment: put this in your `tools.py` to see where you are `print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: output is /home/ubuntu/my_package/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test works because the configuration file is in the current directory, because you're running your main module from the directory of the configuration file.

But if you're using another main file located somewhere else, that could fail.

Here's a clean way to make it work in any case: since your tool is one level below the configuration file, the path to the configuration file can be computed as follows from the `tools.py` module:

```
conf_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'setting.conf')
```

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` yields the directory where `tools.py` is located. Perform one more `dirname` to get the directory where the conf file is located. Now compute absolute name of config file using `os.path.join`

Comment: It's a good way to modify my code. But my code is working now. It means  that someone computes the path to the configuration file. Is the ConfigParser or python interpreter?

Comment: check my edit: you're simply running the tool in the current directory, that's why it works.

Comment: it raises NoSectionError when I run the tool in the lib directory. So the configuration file path depends on where I run the script, not depends on the location of the script which reads configuration file.